# MYSQL-Display hired number of years

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

The question is:

> Display the number of years the employee is hired as NUM_OF_YEARS and sort the list by lastname.

This is the code used on the other pc and it run well.

```
SELECT  `lastname` AS "LASTNAME", 
DATE_FORMAT(`hire_date`,'%d-%M-%Y') AS "HIRED DATE",
TRUNCATE(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),CONVERT(`hire_date`,DATETIME))  / 365 ,0) AS "NO_OF_YEARS",
DATEDIFF(YEAR(), `hire_date`, CURDATE()) AS "DATE"
FROM `activity6`.`employee`;
```

Now as I tried to use Xampp (3.2.2) and run it using the same code above here's the error I got:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '), hire_date, CURDATE()) AS "DATE"
>       FROM activity6.employee' at line 5

Here's the table I created and must be used for the code above.---- 
[image]

So at the same time I need to create another column to show the number of years of these employees up to this date (2019).
I'm really not sure what is the right query to use.

Comment: Do basic debuging. First do convert(), then try Datediff, then add the truncate, when you know what function give you the error check the manual for proper sintaxis

Comment: `This is the code used on the other pc and it run well.` are you using same rdbms in the other pc?

Comment: Please define the calculation for number of years.  It is not obvious what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

In the `DATEDIFF` function, you used 3 parameters, and that function takes  2, i removed the YEAR() parameter:

```
SELECT  `lastname` AS "LASTNAME", 
        DATE_FORMAT(`hire_date`,'%d-%M-%Y') AS "HIRED DATE",
        TRUNCATE(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),CONVERT(`hire_date`,DATETIME))  / 365 ,0) AS "NO_OF_YEARS",
        DATEDIFF( `hire_date`, CURDATE()) AS "DATE"
FROM `activity6`.`employee`;
```